# Facing an Error while trying to Import ModelStep

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, mlops, amazon-sagemaker-debugger, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am trying to import ModelStep using the code

```
from sagemaker.workflow.model_step import ModelStep
```

But it is throwing the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sagemaker.workflow.model_step'

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try updating the SageMaker SDK version and see how it goes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature, in sagemaker-python-sdk, was introduced starting with [release 2.90.0](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/releases/tag/v2.90.0) (16 May 2022).

I suggest always keeping sagemaker updated, they come out with updates very frequently and quite important:

```
pip install -U sagemaker
```